# Sum of two variables in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I have two variables from 1 to 100. I have two buttons. I want one button to print the two variables on the screen and I want one button to print the sum of both the variables. How do I do this? My code is:

```
- (IBAction)addition:(id)sender;
{
    int x = arc4random() %100;
    int y = arc4random() %100;
    [label1 setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x]];
    [label2 setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", y]];
}

- (IBAction)answer:(id)sender;
{
    int z;
    z = x+y;
    answer.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", z];
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? That code looks correct.

Comment: @JackHumphries: You mean besides the fact that his `-answer:` method is leaking?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why he is asking this question about displaying the sum of the two integers on the screen. It wasn't a memory management question.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `x` and `y` instance variables of the class in question you should get what you want.

As-is those variables don't exist after the invocation to `addition:` and the above code doesn't even compile... unless you also happen to have `x` and `y` already declared as ivars in the class and the versions in `addition:` are just shadowing them.

In either case, remove the `int` from `x` and `y` in `addition:`.

Comment: This isn't C++, there's no such thing as a "member variable". They're called instance variables in Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you hace your code configured now, you'd have to declare your `int` values in your Interface file ("`.h` file"). It'd look something like this pseudocode:

```
@interface Class {
    int x;
    int y;

    UILabel *label1;
    UILabel *label2;
    UILabel *answer;
}

-(IBAction)...
```

Then in your `.m` file, you'd just keep it as-is (just remove the `int` declarations for `x` and `y`) and hook up the functions and the outlets in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have problem with answer button... But that should also work... but if not then try below code which should definitely work.

Here you should declare `x` & `y` variable in `.h` file. And dont declare in addition button click.

```
- (IBAction)answer:(id)sender;
{
    int z;
    z = x+y;
    answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", z];
}
```

If you are not having this question, then i would suggest you to please specify exact issue that you are facing..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are ensuring label1 and label2 keeps integer values your answer method can be like

```
- (IBAction)answer:(id)sender;
{
    [answer setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[label1 text] intValue] + [[label2 text] intValue]]];
}
```